# Using columns in bash

Tags: linux, bash, formatting

I've used the column command to split some of my output into 3 different columns. Problem is with the final column, the filetype output is being split into a 4th and 5th column because of the spaces.

Can somebody tell me how to change my code so that output stays under the Filetype column?

```
list_files()
{   
  if [ "$(ls -A ~/.junkdir)" ]
  then
      filesdir=/home/student/.junkdir/*
      echo "Listing files in Junk Directory"      
      output="FILENAME SIZE(BYTES) TYPE \n\n---------------- ---------------- ------------------- "

  for listed_file in $filesdir
  do
      file_name=$(basename "file $listed_file" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
      file_size=$(du --bytes $listed_file | awk '{print $1}')
      file_type=$(file $listed_file | cut -d ' ' -f2-)
      output="$output\n${file_name} ${file_size} ${file_type}\n"
  done

  echo -ne $output | column -t 
  else
  echo 'Junk directory is empty'
  fi
}
```

The output at the moment..

```
Listing files in Junk Directory
FILENAME          SIZE(BYTES)       TYPE
----------------  ----------------  -------------------
files.txt         216               ASCII                text
forLoop           401               Bourne-Again         shell  script,  
ASCII  text  executable
```

Comment: are you allowed to change your separator? the chances are, you can fix it by changing separator.

Comment: I've tried different commands with " column -t" but I can't seem to find the one thats doing the job?

Comment: my `man column` says you can pass `-s sep` to specify your custom separator. if that solves it, i will make it an answer.

Comment: Yeah I've tried the -s, but what seperator would I use? a double space would be ideal but it doesn't seem to take that in.

Comment: have you tried the magical char `$'\0'`?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance mate, can you advise how to implement that? Would I have add that to the end of each variable in my loop so it appears? Or is it only added as a seperator arguement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rarely give full solution, but it seems you are really stuck.

```
list_files2()
{   

  filesdir=/home/student/.junkdir/* 
  printf "FILENAME\1SIZE(BYTES)\1TYPE\1\n\n----------------\1----------------\1-------------------\n"

  for listed_file in $filesdir
  do
      file_name=$(basename "file $listed_file" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
      file_size=$(du --bytes $listed_file | awk '{print $1}')
      file_type=$(file $listed_file | cut -d ' ' -f2-)
      printf "%s\1%s\1%s\n" "${file_name}" "${file_size}" "${file_type}"
  done
}

list_files()
{   
  if [ "$(ls -A ~/.junkdir)" ]
  then
      echo "Listing files in Junk Directory"      
      list_files2 | column -t -s $'\1'
  else
      echo 'Junk directory is empty'
  fi
}
```

I slightly reorganized your code and made some other changes as well. I will explain what I did.

1. `$'\1'` is the `0x01` char. Even though I proposed to use `$'\0'`, it's weird that my version of column has weird interaction with it appearing in the input. But in shell scripting practice, it's generally a bad idea to assume blank separator. In your case, you got caught by space, which is reasonable, because white space has so much overloaded meaning, you cannot prevent it from appearing in a human readable text. The solution to this is to consider using exotic chars like `0x00` or `0x01` as separator instead, which is almost always the case that it won't show up as a part of the text. So it's very safe to use and in fact, it's common in portable shell scripting to use `0x00` as separator.
2. Do not concatenate string like you did. In fact, there are couple problems with it.

   1. one is you keep concatenating string while you don't really need the intermediate result.
   2. another biteback is what if inside of your text, strings like `\n` exist and it should be interpreted as literal? `echo -e` is not going to distinguish that. yet another SO question on the road.
   3. using `printf` in fact is more flavorable in shell, though I use `echo` a lot myself as well. Here the benefit of using `printf` is evident.

I don't have your files so I didn't try it, though I would expect it works. Let me know if there're glitches here and there.

Comment: Some really good advice there mate, thanks a lot. Your script worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try

```
output="$output\n${file_name}\t${file_size}\t${file_type}\n"

...

echo -ne $output
```

Comment: try to keep output with \t and use echo -ne $output | column -s $'\t' -t